# Error with entering a column with a "-" in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am having difficult time with this question:

What is the ‘total price’ of the ‘urgent order’ that placed most recently (having the latest order date).Use the function ‘STR_TO_DATE’ and the column ‘O_ORDER-PRIORITY’, and provide only one sql. (Give the sql that we will get only the amount of the total price by running it, no other unnecessary information)

My SQL is:

```
SELECT SUM(o_totalprice)
FROM orders
GROUP BY o_custkey
HAVING o_order-priority = '1-URGENT'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(orders.O_ORDERDATE,'%m/%d/%Y') 
DESC
```

Issue:
When I enter this query I have an error telling me that it cannot read o_order-priority due to the “-“.Can someone give me direction with how to fix this error?

Comment: Your column contains a hyphen `o_order-priority` wrap it in backticks `\`` - SQL thinks you want to do math.

Comment: You need to escape bad column names, so use `o_order-priority` in backticks.  Or, better yet, change the name to something that does not require escape characters.  I vote to close these types of questions as being typographical errors.  I removed the sql-server tag because the syntax is obviously MySQL.

Comment: smarter just to rename it

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: In other words, MySQL is interpreting `o_order-priority` as `o_order` **minus** `priority`

Comment: This question has been answered. You can just delete your question now.

Comment: Lets say I did change the name, is the syntax of the SQLstill right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- why not an answer?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry but why do people put their answer as a comment?  Isn't it better to create an answer?  I dont think the OP can accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Because, 9 times out of 10 when an OP says "is my syntax right", is a sign that they haven't tried it, and leaves room for confusion, and may not even work after doing the fix because of something else along the line (and commenting back and forth with the OP all over again). It's up to the OP to try it and check for errors. There's an answer below, so if OP chooses to accept it, great.

Comment: The OP has stated that the issue they are having is with the "-" sign which you have correctly identified and answered in a comment.  Isn't it better to put answers as answers so that if the OP does eventually try it and it works, they can accept the answer?  Even if there is another issue, the OP can comment on your answer.  I just wonder what the motivation is for deleting the question alltogether as that will help no one.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ There's already an answer covering the error, so I don't need to put one in. The OP can accept it. If he/she hasn't gotten back to us, then that remains unclear why. OP hasn't responded to my earlier comment of "Did you try it?". In not doing so, how are we to know whether it worked or not? Maybe the person is still having problems with the code; it's anybody's guess.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I totally agree with you.  I'm just trying to learn when it is better to put the answer in a comment, and why.  Your first comment was made before any answers existed and certainly before the OP asked about "correct syntax"

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Believe me Phil, I take this from experience. Many a time in the past have I put in an answer right away in thinking the obvious would fix an OP's code, but it only led to commenting back and forth in my answer for about an hour, then having to setup a complete DB in trying to figure out why "my" code works but won't work for the OP. It's a classic *Live and Learn* question which I rather not open a proverbial "can of worms". When someone doesn't respond, is also another "live and learn" situation and a "sign" ;) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2):

Change a little your code:

Surround your column name that's causing trouble with backticks `

```
SELECT SUM(o_totalprice)
FROM orders
GROUP BY o_custkey
HAVING `o_order-priority` = '1-URGENT'
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(orders.O_ORDERDATE,'%m/%d/%Y') 
DESC
```

But my recommendation is that you must to change name for o_order_priority for example

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT o_totalprice
FROM orders
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(o_orderdate,'%d/%m/%Y')
AND `o_order-priority`='1-URGENT'
ORDER BY o_orderdate DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Why does your answer resemble so much to a question you asked http://stackoverflow.com/q/27218760/

Comment: Answers just happen to be similar.